# Render shows nothing?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm doing some animation and when I try to render the animation it doesn't show the anything, but it does show it in render-view mode in the 3D Viewport.

I've tried turning sequencing off, nothing.

This is my viewport

[image: 3D View[1]]

[image]

Comment: OK. I've got a little bit further. Turns out it was to do with the compositing nodes, but now I just had a black render instead. I've turned off sequencing so I'm not sure why its doing that. :(

Comment: You should upload a simplified .blend, else troubleshooting is difficult

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up